# Prompting Webkit transition

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have a page with three boxes.  What I'm trying to have happen is when I click on the third box, box 1 is prompted to fade away at one speed and box two fades away at a slower one.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.box { /* this style applies only to the 'before' transition state */
opacity:1;} 
div.fadeAway { /* give the transition rules to "after" state */
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s; }  
div.fadeAway2 { /* give the transition rules to "after" state */
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 5s; }  
</style>

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box" 
style="width:100px; 
height:100px; 
background-color:green;"> 
Tap to fade 
</div>


    <div class="box2" 
style="width:100px; 
height:100px; 
background-color:red;">
Tap to fade 
</div>

<div class="box3" 
style="width:100px; 
height:100px; 
background-color:blue;" 
this.onclick=".box2 .box3.className = 'fadeaway''fadeaway2'"> 
Tap to fade 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: here's the fiddle I put together for it  http://jsfiddle.net/mCjmt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .box 
    {     
        opacity:1;
        color: white;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    } 

    #box1
    {
        background-color: green;
    }

    #box2
    {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #box3
    {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    div.fadeAway1
    { 
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
        -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; 
    }  

    div.fadeAway2 
    { 
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
        -webkit-transition-duration: 5s; 
    }  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Tap to fade</div>


<script>
    (function () { 
        document.getElementById('box3').addEventListener('click', function() {
            for ( var i = 1, stop = 2; i <= stop; i += 1) {
                document.getElementById('box' + i).className = "box fadeAway" + i; 
            }
        }, false); 
    })();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example implementing jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
    .box 
    {     
        opacity:1;
        color: white;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    } 

    #box1
    {
        background-color: green;
    }

    #box2
    {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #box3
    {
        background-color: blue;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Tap to fade</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $("#box3").click(function() {
            for ( var i = 1, stop = 2; i <= stop; i += 1) {
                $('#box' + i).fadeTo(500 * (i*2),0); 
            }
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay, so this certainly works, thanks for doing that for me.  So the reason I had asked was because this was a simpler version of what I was ultimately hoping to do, which was animate a 3d set up in webkit: http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/slider.html  I had wanted to animate the layers collapsing up and down on each other meeting in the middle as a "singular" layer and then have it rotate up.

Comment: I'm having trouble changing what you came up with to make it effect webkit 3d stuff.  The jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9BEUQ/  for the start would be animating the change translate3d(-14px, -120px, 3px) to                    translate3d(-14px, -85px, 3px) for both layers.  I'm having trouble getting both of these to change onclick.

Comment: So i'm trying to take baby steps, http://jsfiddle.net/VfURZ/10/ I'm trying to get this fiddle to change two properties for 4 divs.  Each div has a parent and a child, separate classes, separate ids.  I'm not sure how to update your script have it retrieve two element ids.  I'd like to do these transitions with javascript and webkit not jquery.

Comment: A couple of things: the '<script>' tag in the JavaScript section was causing an issue. And, there was a misspelling 'getElemetnById' instead of 'getElementById.'  Also, the CSS '#container1/2' id selector was overriding the '.container' styles. You can add " ! important" to the ".container" styles or re-work the styles.  I tried to save the **jsfiddle** page, but since I haven't used that much, I'm not sure that is how the site works. :)  BTW, it's never a  bad idea to test your pages in Chrome or Firefox developer tools, so you can see JavaScript errors, etc.